# Is there any "standard" definition of "linguistic input"?

Tags: language-acquisition, psycholinguistics, second-lang-acquisition, philosophy-of-language

Recently, I've started wondering how to characterize "linguistic input" and realized that the notion is very rarely unpacked. It seems as if everyone takes it to be obvious, and immediately goes to more specific topics such as "how parents modify the linguistic input to facilitate children's language acquisition", "the role of the linguistic input in L1 versus L2 acquisition", etc. But there has to be some precise, fairly standard definition of what linguistic input is. I would be most grateful for any hints and/or references.

Comment: One of the terms for the linguistic input directed at children is 'child directed speech', there's been a fair bit of research in this area and it's likely they have some kind of definition of what is and isn't CDS. Of course, communication between speakers that is not directed at children but is audible to them also forms part of the linguistic input.